# "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" while trying to use AFNetworking Multi-Part Upload using NSURLSessionUploadTask

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload an mp3 file to our server using the **AFNetworking** Multi-Part request using **NSURLSessionUploadTask**.

I am using the code from AFNetworking example.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSProgress *progress = nil;

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```

When doing so the application gets an *"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" thrown in the "_CFStreamSetDispatchQueue"*. It seems like this error is being thrown after the application goes through the **needNewBodyStream** delegate method.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

[image: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" thrown in the "_CFStreamSetDispatchQueue"]
[image]